# how to reload or refresh data in treeTable in php

Tags: php, treetable

i have issue on use treeTable while reload data and after save and update data form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const datajson = <?php echo $data_json  ?>;
    $('#tablejson').treeTable({

        "data": datajson,
        "collapsed": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        },
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "columns": [{
                "data": "nama_module",
            },
            {
                "data": "controller",
            },
            {
                "data": "function",

            },
            {
                "data": "nm_group",

            },
            {
                "data": "label",

            },
            {
                "data": "btn"
            }
        ],
        "order": [],
    });

    $('#btn-reload').click(function() {
        $('#tablejson').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

i try to click button for reload tabel use `$('#tablejson').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();` but not working, this is happen while i use treeTable, if i use datatable only its work for reload or refresh table.

does anyone have the same case with me ? thanks

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the tour and read how to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i found a solution in my case, i use code like this

```
 $('#btn-reload').click(function() {
        $('#tablejson').DataTable()
            .order([2, 'desc'])
            .draw();
    });
```

thanks....